# "Насчет" или "на счет"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно писать: "на счет" или "насчет"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Все зависит от контекста. Но проще всего проверять так: если между "на" и "счет" можно вставить слово, то пишется раздельно. И наоборот.
Пример: *"Перевести деньги на счет" - "Перевести деньги на депозитный счет".

"А насчет вас я подумаю".*

Answer (score 7):

***Насчёт*** работы — производный предлог: можно заменить непроизводным предлогом **о**.
*Положить деньги **на счёт*** — существительное с непроизводным предлогом **на**: есть пояснительное слово.

Answer (score 5):

Для себя пользуюсь таким правилом: если "насчёт" можно заменить словом "относительно", пишу слитно. Если перед счёт можно вставить, к примеру, слово "банковский", - раздельно.

– Что вы думаете насчёт (относительно) квартального отчёта?
– Отчёт готов, премию можете перечислить мне на (банковский) счёт!